# If hot module reload works properly in vue native-script?

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

I did everything according to guide https://nativescript-vue.org/en/docs/getting-started/installation. I installed a testing app and try to change the message on Home component, but i see that only css reloads on the fly. No errors, no issues or notes, just my android emulator reacts only on css changing, but not on js changing. At the same time, after every code changing (css or js) in console, I see *JS: [HMR][31d47f755865bfccabe9] success | Successfully applied update.*
Knowing all previous problem with HRM that native-script vue used to have, do these problems still exist?
My package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "example-app",
  "main": "app/app.ts",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@nativescript/core": "~8.3.0",
    "@nativescript/theme": "~3.0.2",
    "nativescript-vue": "~2.9.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nativescript/android": "8.3.1",
    "@nativescript/preview-cli": "1.0.1",
    "@nativescript/types": "~8.3.0",
    "@nativescript/webpack": "~5.0.6",
    "@types/node": "~17.0.21",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "~2.9.0",
    "typescript": "~4.5.5",
    "vue": "~2.6.12"
  }
}
```

My webpack.config.js

```js
const webpack = require("@nativescript/webpack");

module.exports = (env) => {
    webpack.init(env);

    // Learn how to customize:
    // https://docs.nativescript.org/webpack

    return webpack.resolveConfig();
};
```

My tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["app/*"],
      "@/*": ["app/*"]
    },
    "typeRoots": ["types"],
    "types": ["node"],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["app", "types"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "platforms"],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped using NativeScript hmr years ago. It's always given me issues. I've connected with people from the core NativeScript team who said they do the same.

I run my builds with `--no-hmr` and just use the full app reload.